# How to access elements using list comprehensions / double for-loops? Problem solving IndexError.

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension, index-error

I am trying to learn list-comprehensions, and for that I am trying to print the fourth letter for each city in the following list:

```
word_list = ["Amsterdam", "Hannover", "Milano", "Paris", "London", "Glasgow", "Dublin", "Tokyo", "Canberra"]
```

I think I need a double for loop here, one to access the cities in the list, and one to access the letters of each city. However, when I try to put this inside a list comprehension like:

```
listcomprehension = [letter[3] for word in word_list for letter in word]
print(listcomprehension)
```

I get the following error:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I tought it could be an error with my list-comprehension (Since I am new to those), so I tried to achieve my goal using a normal double for-loop:

```
for word in word_list:
    for letter in word:
        print(letter[3])
```

What am I doing wrong here? All cities have more than 4 letters, so I don't understand why this error is happening. I am rather new to programming, and I am still often confused when using double for-loops... Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: `letter[3]` - what kind of letter has four letters in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`letter` is already a single letter, `letter[3]` doesn't exist because `letter` only contains one letter.

You don't need two loops because strings can be indexed.

```
listcomprehension = [word[3] for word in word_list]
```

or

```
for word in word_list:
    print(word[3])
```

Comment: Thanks.. I understand this.  I thought I could not directly access strings by using indices because strings are immutable?

Comment: @Psychotechnopath - no - you can access strings using indices. What you **can't** do is access the 4th letter on a string that only has ONE letter.

Comment: but I cannot MODIFY strings by using indices right?  So you can ACCESS immutable objects in python by using indices, but you cannot modify them?

Comment: @Psychotechnopath you can't modify strings in any way as they are immutable. All you can do is create a new string with the contents you want. That is unrelated to using indices

Comment: @Agile_Eagle nosklo thank you both =) All is clear to me now!

Comment: @Psychotechnopath No problem

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two loops you can simply do this:

```
word_list = ["Amsterdam", "Hannover", "Milano", "Paris", "London", "Glasgow", "Dublin", "Tokyo", "Canberra"]

for item in word_list:
    print(item[3])
```

The mistake in your code is that when you create two for loops, you iterate over each letter. Each letter is stored as a string with a length of 1. So you cannot call `letter[4]`.

Comment: I don't know, I voted you back up... Thanks for answering.

Comment: @Psychotechnopath Thanks a lot

Comment: @Will I got the downvote before I added that sentence. Anyway your point is correct I will edit the answer

Comment: I believe you got the downvote because you answered with code without explaining the error. You edited and added the explanation later, I hope whoever downvoted you returns and removes the downvote.